# Trouble getting the location in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the zipcode for the users current location for later use in the program.

I've narrowed down the issue to the `.getLatitude()` and `.getLongitude()`. For some reason, the latitude and longitude is never set with the methods. Does anyone know why this is and how I can fix it? (I did set the permissions for the fine and coarse locations.) My code is below:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3600, 1000, new LocationListener()
        {
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
            public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
            {
                if(loc != null)
                {
                    lat = (int)(loc.getLatitude());
                    lon = (int)(loc.getLongitude());
                }
            }
        });

        t.setText("Lat: " + lat + " and long: " + lon);

        Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try
        {
            addresses = geo.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            t.setText("Could not find the Zip Code");
        }

        if(addresses.equals(null))
            t.setText("Couldn't find the zip code");

        else
        {
            zipcode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode(); 
            t.setText("Zip Code: " + zipcode);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

These two links may help you.. [This blog has nice explanation with sample code](http://www.rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/01/get-current-location-coordinates-city.html)  Also you can refer this second link [Using Gps can do and check this](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/)